# How ejs Extract values from object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, ejs

I am using Sequelize where I fetch all the data from a table using **findAll**. Which is basically an Array of objects. What seems to be confusing is that the data I am showing as output nested under objects. (Sounds Confusing? Let me clarify)

So, Let's I have this Short Code

[image]

Here if I run this code, it will give me undefine because **father** lies in parent, for which I have to use **user.parent.father**, Right?

Okay, now on Fetching data from table in my code, 
[image]

I console.log my first row, for which I get this.
[image]

Now here the values which I need lies in dataValues.

In my ejs file. I am using simple for-of loop

[image]

Now my Question is why am I not getting undefined for product.title , product.imageUrl and so on? It is supposed to get those data by product.dataValues.title. Because It lies in another object names dataValues.

Comment: The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables.**It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object**

Comment: Not sure if the `console.log` you show is truncated but properties should be there, just after all these internals (`dataValues`, `_previousDataValues` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, when a value is initialized by Sequelize, your object's prototype is set to [`Model`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/model.js) (the class is too long to copy-paste it here).

When you create your model, Sequelize calls `init` on it (line 424) and which in turn calls `refreshAttributes`.

This one calls `Object.defineProperty` to define both the getter and the setter for each property you have defined in the metadata (line 1238).

The getter and setter are set to `get` and `set` functions respectively (lines 1095 to 1103).

This actually means that

```
instance.field
```

is just a property wrapped over

```
instance.get('field')
```

This corresponds with [their docs](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/instance/) which says

> Instance instances operate with the concept of a `dataValues` property, which stores the actual values represented by the instance. By default, the values from dataValues can also be accessed directly from the Instance, that is:
>
> `instance.field`
>
> is the same as
>
> `instance.get('field')`
>
> is the same as
>
> `instance.getDataValue('field')`